# MySQL LIKE and MATCH results query

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain why

```
column  LIKE '%board%'
```

returns more results than

```
MATCH (column) AGAINST('board' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

is it because match against ignores words like 'Blackboard', 'Backboard' etc

Is there away to get MATCH AGAINST return Blackboard, backboard etc?

Answer (score 3):

`MATCH (column) AGAINST('keyword...` will match against the literal string provided, where as `LIKE "%keyword%"` will match if a word contains the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

```
MATCH (column) AGAINST('board*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

There are a lot of good examples of search queries there.

Comment: Not sure if you can do `*board*`, per the docs `The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it should be appended to the word to be affected. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.`

Comment: the counts are still off, with the wildcard. For example 20 MATCH AGAINST versus 50 for LIKE '%board%'

Comment: what are the actual differences.

Comment: "Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator. " What about words that contain words/tokens?